# RequireJS fails loading required javascript with cache disabled, but only sometimes

Tags: magento-2.1

About 30% of page loads fail to load with errors like this:
[image]

It is because require JS doesn't do it's job and load.  If you hit F5 a few times it will start working again, also if you have cache enabled, it almost never happens.

It totally breaks the page as no further JS executes.  It makes development a constant pain.

Edit: Full log but it will change what it says it errors on, because requirejs is just failing to do it's job:

```
Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.
[Learn More]
product.html
Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead.
jquery.js:4932:7
JQMIGRATE: Logging is active
jquery-migrate.js:21:2
TypeError: $.datepicker is undefined
[Learn More]
product.html:3602:13
<anonymous>
http://devsite.com/product.html:3602:13
execCb
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1650:24
check
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:866:43
enable/</<
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1113:29
bind/<
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:132:20
emit/<
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1156:21
each
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:57:31
emit
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1155:17
check
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:917:25
enable
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1143:17
init
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:774:21
callGetModule
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1170:17
completeLoad
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1564:25
onScriptLoad
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1671:21
TypeError: $(...).swMegamenu is not a function
[Learn More]
product.html:567:9
<anonymous>
http://devsite.com/product.html:567:9
execCb
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1650:24
check
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:866:43
enable/</<
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1113:29
bind/<
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:132:20
emit/<
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1156:21
each
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:57:31
emit
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1155:17
check
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:917:25
enable
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1143:17
init
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:774:21
callGetModule
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1170:17
completeLoad
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1564:25
onScriptLoad
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1671:21
TypeError: $.widget is not a function
[Learn More]
collapsible.js:20:5
<anonymous>
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/mage/collapsible.js:20:5
execCb
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1650:24
check
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:866:43
enable
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1143:17
init
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:774:21
callGetModule
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1170:17
completeLoad
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1544:21
onScriptLoad
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1671:21
TypeError: $.widget is not a function
[Learn More]
modal.js:46:5
<anonymous>
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal.js:46:5
execCb
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1650:24
check
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:866:43
enable/</<
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1113:29
bind/<
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:132:20
emit/<
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1156:21
each
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:57:31
emit
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1155:17
check
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:917:25
enable
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1143:17
init
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:774:21
callPlugin/</<
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:959:33
bind/<
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:132:20
emit/<
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1156:21
each
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:57:31
emit
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1155:17
check
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:917:25
enable
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1143:17
init
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:774:21
callPlugin/</load<
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:991:25
bind/<
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:132:20
loadContent/<
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/mage/requirejs/text.js:155:17
getContent/xhr.onreadystatechange
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/mage/requirejs/text.js:122:21
TypeError: $.ui is undefined
[Learn More]
jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js:18:2
<anonymous>
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js:18:2
execCb
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1650:24
check
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:866:43
enable
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1143:17
init
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:774:21
callGetModule
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1170:17
completeLoad
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1544:21
onScriptLoad
http://devsite.com/static/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1671:21
Password fields present on an insecure (http://) page. This is a security risk that allows user login credentials to be stolen.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems initially some JS code is not loading and that is throwing consequent errors. Post your complete browser error log.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue I described.  If you reload the same page, the error will go away eventually, that is the entire log.  It is a problem because I have to reload a page sometimes 10 times to get it to load right.

Comment: Is it possible to share your domain name to view the website ?

Comment: I can't share the domain sorry :( I pasted the full log in the original question though

Comment: @N. Karthix Kannan I have some javascript code error with bootstrap. Could you have a look my website : https://dev.kbethos.com/

Comment: @Wolfe I can't see any errors in the console. It is pretty clean.